# Menu Item icon getting overlapped in API 23

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, menu, badge

I was creating a cart menu icon with Badge and layler-list but I found that on API 23 the menu icon is getting unwanted background.

[image]

**activity_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_cart"
        android:title="Cart"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**ic_menu_cart.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/cart"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <!-- set a place holder Drawable so android:drawable isn't null -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_badge"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cart" />
</layer-list>
```

below is the code to update the cart count.

```
  public static void setBadgeCount(Context context, LayerDrawable icon, String count) {

        BadgeDrawable badge;

        // Reuse drawable if possible
        Drawable reuse = icon.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge);
        if (reuse != null && reuse instanceof BadgeDrawable) {
            badge = (BadgeDrawable) reuse;
        } else {
            badge = new BadgeDrawable(context);
        }

        badge.setCount(count);
        icon.mutate();
        icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge, badge);
    }
```

I have created the the xml for different API's, but didn't work.
I want to remove the background.
Kindly help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am understand you have to add badge count and icon. So add below way it works.

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/notification_layout"
```

in the `<item>` and Create `notification_layout.xml` layout and set what you want.

so your `activity_main.xml` looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart1"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_cart"
        android:title="Cart"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="ABD"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/notification_layout" />
</menu>
```

**notification_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="40.0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
<!-- Menu Item Image -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigation_cart_white" />
<!-- Badge Count -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_notifcation_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="15.0dip"
        android:minWidth="15.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="3.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="3.0dip"
        android:textSize="10.0sp"
        android:background="@drawable/TextView_design"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output like this :**

[image]

Comment: Could you help me with notification_layout.xml code.

Comment: @KuldeepDubey see i add my `notificaton.layout.xml` file now change the image and see the result.

Comment: things are still not working, am I suppose to make any changes in my activity_menu.xml or ic_menu_cart.xml.

Comment: i have  exactly did the things you have suggested in the answer

Comment: @KuldeepDubey now create `notification_layout.xml` file and delete your `ic_menu_cart.xml` and one more thing you have to create `notification_layout.xml` in your `layout folder` not `menu folder`.

Comment: deleting ic_menu_cart.xml won't create an error in activity_menu.xml?

Comment: `ic_menu_cart` is your image which is inside the `drawable` folder. `ic_menu_cart` is your cart image. don't create file it is your image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131865/discussion-between-kuldeep-dubey-and-ironman).